# Sharpen an image with a linear filter in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I would like to read an image and sharpen it using a linear filter, which is this matrix:

```
H =  [-0.5 -0.5 -0.5; -0.5 5 -0.5; -0.5 -0.5 -0.5]
```

I know about ImageMagick, is there any possibility to do just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is applying a Convolution filter to an image, for that you can use PHP's built in  `imageconvolution()` [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php) function.

For usage, see [Magilvia](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php#104006)'s example on php.net modified for your purpose:

```
<?php 
    $sharpenMatrix = array 
    ( 
        array(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), 
        array(-0.5, 5, -0.5), 
        array(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) 
    ); 

    // calculate the sharpen divisor 
    $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $sharpenMatrix));            

    $offset = 0; 

    // apply the matrix 
    imageconvolution($img, $sharpenMatrix, $divisor, $offset); 
?>
```

`$img` is a PHP image the convolution matrix (sharpening filter) is applied on